# gpg: key 7F0CEB10: "Richard Kreuter <richard@10gen.com>" not changed

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am try to install monodb with rails 4.0.13 but mongodb can not install. I am try following commands:-

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
sudo echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install mongodb-10gen
```

In first command show results:-

```
xecuting: /tmp/tmp.1XA4uBEGIs/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv
7F0CEB10
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7F0CEB10: "Richard Kreuter <richard@10gen.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I did not found whats a problem. But I am run all commands mongo is install but I am start mongodb service so that time show result is:-

```
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
```

I am using these all versions:-

```
Ruby :- ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Rails :- Rails 4.0.13
Gem :- 2.6.11
Bundle :- Bundler version 1.14.6
```

Please tell us. How to solve that problem. I am did not find out suitable solution.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you trying to install? It looks like you're following some very old instructions; 10gen is circa 2013 or older. Try the current instructions to [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition).

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6

Comment: MongoDB 2.4.6 was released in August, 2013 and the 2.4 (and 2.6) release series is no longer supported. Do you have a specific requirement to install an obsolete version of MongoDB, or can you install a supported version (currently 3.0 or newer)? If this is a new deployment I'd suggest starting with the latest production release which will be 3.4.x.